# Data persistence between Flask api services in python

Tags: python, api, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have below two api services written in python :

```
@app.route('/data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = pd.read_csv(r'data_PT.csv')
        data = data.head(20)

        return jsonify(data.to_json(orient='records'))
    

@app.route('/summary', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def summary():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = pd.read_csv(r'data_PT.csv')
        summary = data.describe()
        return jsonify(summary.to_json(orient='records'))
```

My problem is I have to read my input data for both the services again.Is there any method where I can save this data and pass to other services without loading the data again or is there any method where I can save my data,so that if my server get closed, the next time when I restart my server I do not have to reload my data again.

Comment: Actually the question is not clear when you restart server why will data get reloaded. Data gets reloaded when you call these endpoints. If you are calling these services from a front end then you have an option to store data in localstorage. Please update the question with more info.

Comment: I want to pass the data read from first service to another service which shows the summary of the data, without reading the file again and again.